# @OneToOne mapping JPA: unknown column in field list

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I have a database as follows

```
Table Enterprise
ent_id (PK)
loc_id
ent_name

Table Location
loc_id (PK)
loc_name
```

So I want to add a field into the Enterprise model class: "Location" which is a @OneToOne relationship. Unfortunately, when adding this field, the application doesn't work anymore.

The code in the Enterprise class for Location:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="loc_id",referencedColumnName="loc_id")
private Location location;
```

With a getter & setter for location.

I get the following error when adding this Location field:

> PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
>
> [...]
>
> Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'enterprise0_.location' in 'field list'

It seems to me that it is searching for a column 'location' in the database, but this column isn't in the database. It should use the loc_id column instead! I tried adding @Transient, but that doesn't work.

Thanks for any help!

> Enterprise Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Enterprise")
public class Enterprise implements Serializable {
private int entId;
private int locId;
private String entName;
private int entDescription;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "enterprise")
private List<SalesOrder> salesOrders;

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ent_id")
public int getEntId() {
    return entId;
}

public void setEntId(int entId) {
    this.entId = entId;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "loc_id")
public int getLocId() {
    return locId;
}

public void setLocId(int locId) {
    this.locId = locId;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "ent_name")
public String getEntName() {
    return entName;
}

public void setEntName(String entName) {
    this.entName = entName;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "ent_description")
public int getEntDescription() {
    return entDescription;
}

public void setEntDescription(int entDescription) {
    this.entDescription = entDescription;
}

//bi-directional one-to-one association to Location
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="loc_id",referencedColumnName="loc_id")
private Location location;


public Location getLocation() {
    return this.location;
}

public void setLocation(Location location) {
    this.location = location;
}
```

> Location class

```
private int locId;
private String locCountry;
private int locPostcode;
private String locCity;
private String locStreet;
private int locNumber;
private Integer locSubNumber;


@Override
public String toString() {
    return locStreet + " " + locNumber + ", " + locPostcode  + " " + locCity + ", " + locCountry;
}

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "loc_id")
public int getLocId() {
    return locId;
}

public void setLocId(int locId) {
    this.locId = locId;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "loc_country")
public String getLocCountry() {
    return locCountry;
}

public void setLocCountry(String locCountry) {
    this.locCountry = locCountry;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "loc_postcode")
public int getLocPostcode() {
    return locPostcode;
}

public void setLocPostcode(int locPostcode) {
    this.locPostcode = locPostcode;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "loc_city")
public String getLocCity() {
    return locCity;
}

public void setLocCity(String locCity) {
    this.locCity = locCity;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "loc_street")
public String getLocStreet() {
    return locStreet;
}

public void setLocStreet(String locStreet) {
    this.locStreet = locStreet;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "loc_number")
public int getLocNumber() {
    return locNumber;
}

public void setLocNumber(int locNumber) {
    this.locNumber = locNumber;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "loc_sub_number")
public Integer getLocSubNumber() {
    return locSubNumber;
}

public void setLocSubNumber(Integer locSubNumber) {
    this.locSubNumber = locSubNumber;
}
```

Comment: csn you post the exact mappings of you classes.

Comment: @PrerakTiwari I added the classes!

Comment: why do you have both int locId and Location location at the same time in your Enterprise class? Your @OneToOne to Location already gives you the locId attribute.. And you say that Location-Enterprise is bi directional, but its not defined in the Location side..

Comment: @mendieta that worked!! Thanks a lot :). Can you post it as answer? I will then mark your answer as a solution.

Comment: glad it helped! I posted it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `int locId` from your Enterprise class, since you already have declared `Location location`, which includes that attribute.

Also, you mentioned that Location-Enterprise is bi directional, but the relationship is not defined in the Location side